# cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from component

Tags: java

Get the error in project

```
    private void revalidate()
{
    m_pageMax = m_viewPanel.getPageCount();
    spinnerModel.setMaximum(new Integer(m_pageMax));

    //  scroll area (page size dependent)
    centerScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension
        (m_viewPanel.getPaperWidth()+30, m_viewPanel.getPaperHeight()+15));
    centerScrollPane.getViewport().setViewSize(new Dimension
        (m_viewPanel.getPaperWidth()+2*m_viewPanel.getMarginSize(true),
        m_viewPanel.getPaperHeight()+2*m_viewPanel.getMarginSize(true)));

    //  Report Info
    setTitle(Msg.getMsg(m_ctx, "Report") + ": " + m_reportEngine.getName() + "  " + Env.getHeader(m_ctx, 0));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer ();
    sb.append(m_viewPanel.getPaper().toString(m_ctx))
        .append(" - ").append(Msg.getMsg(m_ctx, "DataCols")).append("=")
        .append(m_reportEngine.getColumnCount())
        .append(", ").append(Msg.getMsg(m_ctx, "DataRows")).append("=")
        .append(m_reportEngine.getRowCount());
    statusBar.setStatusLine(sb.toString());
    //
    setPage(m_pageNo);
}   //  revalidate
```

Get error on revalidate method that "cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from component"

Comment: Referrer to some of the available tutorials online

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.